# Google script Unzip password protected files

Tags: google-apps-script

I can unzip files in google drive if they are not password protected. Is it possible to unzip password protected files?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid such a function doesn't exist yet as google doesn't have a password class.
I suggest you [submit a request to Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) or add to this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025)